# How to recompose without onClick?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why for recomposing, we must use an event like onClick from a Button?

for example, my code is:

```
if (movieSearchinfo.movieorserie == "serie") {

val serie1 = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (serie1.value == true) {
    
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .verticalScroll(
                                rememberScrollState()
                            )
                            .height(100.dp)
                    ) {
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(4.dp)
                        ) {
                            items(movieDetail.value) { movieDetail ->
                                if (movieDetail.se == "1") {
                                    serie1.value = true
                                    GetSerieCard(
                                        Modifier,
                                        movieDetail
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

when after my last if, I say: serie1.value = true, why jetpack doesn't recompose and doesn't make the UI of my first if? because the serie1.value became true now?

I saw somewhere that we can use:

`currentComposer.composition.recompose()`

but I don't know what he meant. does anyone know how we can use it? I used it somehow but it didn't work. maybe I used it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why for recomposing, we must use an event like onClick from a Button?

You don't necessarily need a button click for a Composable to recompose. Instance of `MutableState` that is read by a Composable, scope or conditional code block should change to trigger recomposition.

Value of `MutableState` can change in various ways including user interaction, finite or infinite animation, asynchronous operation result such as web request  or query from a database returning a result.

For conditional code blocks like

```
if (serie1.value == true) {
   // Composable content 
}
```

condition must be true to enter recomposition. But in your snippet you change it to true if it enters Composition and then user clicks the `Button` which doesn't look possible with your snippet.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want user to change the serie1.value to true. i do it myself after the last if, where i say            if (movieDetail.se == "1") {
                                    serie1.value = true
                                  
                                                            shouldn't it recompose then? I know the condition is met and the value change to true. so why it doesn't recompose the UI?

Comment: when I change serie1.value inside a Button on click, it works and execute the if code block. but I don't know why it doesn't do that when I change it to true inside my code. I know it change it to true, but it doesn't recompose and doesn't execute the if code block

Comment: thanks man. you were right. I doubted and printed it's value and found out that it didn't change to true. now I know what to do.